# Android app wont install on Htc Wildfire issue

Tags: java, android, htc-android

I have tested my app on many devices such as Samsung Xperia, Galaxy, HTC desire and HTC droid and it works fine. However when I try to install on a Htc Wildfire from the marketplace I get the error "Incompatible with this device". Does anyone have any advice as to what is different about the Wildfire that stops my app from installing?

Here is the Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/applicationicontransparent">
    <activity android:name="com.myapp.test"
              android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.myapp.test.act1" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>


</application>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3"/>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Chances are they could have their own named permissions. Just throwing ideas out there.

Comment: Can you post your whole AndroidManifest?  Could be something else.

Comment: I have posted the manifest CaseyB . Does this mean that my "android:minSdkVersion" should be 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wildfire is a QVGA device.  Make sure you are targeting API 4 or later, or have explicitly said in your manifest that you support small screens.

Also you can use "aapt dump badging  to see the permissions you will be requesting from the perspective of market.